# Get fields from a collection field in .theme

Tags: 8, entities

I would like to know how I have to collect the field collection to get the fields it contains

```
$fieldItemList = $node->field_collection_gallery;
$fieldCollection = $fieldItemList[0];
$fieldCollectionItem = FieldCollectionItem::load($fieldCollection->value);
```

Comment: Use `->target_id` instead of `->value`. Now that you have the field collection item it should be no problem to access the fields. You can use `$node->field_collection->referencedEntities()`, this is quicker

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$fieldCollectionItems = $node->get('field_collection_gallery');

    foreach ($fieldCollectionItems as $key => $item) {
      $fcItem = FieldCollectionItem::load($item->value);

      if ($fcItem instanceof FieldCollectionItem) {
        $fcValue = $fcItem->get('field_name')->getValue();
      }
    }
```

The `$fcValue` variable should contain the value from the field in the field collection item.

You have to replace the `field_name` with your own field name in the last line in the `foreach()` loop.